# How to make testFlight still available to internal testers when the build is released to App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

As far as I know, once selected build is approved and released to App Store, all testFlight version below the build will automatically expired.

Say, under Version 1.0.0, there are build 1070, 1071, 1072, if build 1072 is selected for shipping to App Store, all build below 1072 will expired.

Is there any way that I can keep accessibility of testFlight's build for my team after the build is released to App Store? Is this appropriate?

Comment: Why would you want testers to keep testing an out-of-date version of the app? Why not have them install the up-to-date App Store version?

Comment: Well, tried explain to my manager many times, stills, colleague will panic when they find their testFlight app is expired and unusable, so it's kinda saving my effort to deal with these people :)

Comment: Well, I think you should consider other third parties such as AppCenter, Deplogate, etc. Or buy an enterprise account and then build in-house your own.

Comment: Thx for comment, enterprise did support internal distribution, but we also need to publish to AppStore for business partners, which is prohibits by enterprise.

Comment: Releasing a version to the App Store doesn't affect TestFlight versions in any way. It does not expire previous builds or versions.  People often automatically update their TestFlight versions but you can select old versions in the testflight app and disable automatic updates too.

Answer (score 1):

What most developers do is distinguish between dev builds and release builds. Our TestFlight builds are dev builds and they do not expire until after the normal 90 days, even though we do a release to the App Store every 14 days.

Comment: Separate dev builds and release build sounds a solid approach, how do you manage these builds releasing efforts?  
Since we have no CI/CD tools, current shipping process is sent to testFlight via Xcode, and project manager will pick build to apply to App Store.

Comment: You can use carrier pigeon for all that it matters. :) The key thing is that the dev builds have a different bundle id from the release builds. We have `dev` builds and `release` builds with one bundle id, and `release-appstore` builds with another bundle id. The `dev` builds are used for testing locallying, the `release` builds go to TestFlight, and the `release-appstore` builds go to the AppStore. — However, along with the comment of @Paulw11 above, I also doubt the premise of your original question.